# Merge multiple MySQL results from PHP, use same collation/sorting

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, character-encoding

I am using PHP to report on and merge information across three MySQL databases. The data from MySQL is basically:

```
SELECT email, money FROM accounts ORDER BY email
```

And in PHP I implemented a merge (pasting for fun):

```
$inputs = array(); // Elements of ['row'=>array, 'statement'=>PDOStatement]
while (count($inputs) > 0) {
  $minimumInput = NULL;
  $currentOutput = new OutputRow();
  // Find minimum input
  foreach ($inputs as $input) {
    list($row, $statement) = $input;
    if (is_null($minimumInput) || $row->email < $minimumInput->email) {
      $minimumInput = $input['row'];
    }
  }
  // Merge all matching inputs
  $currentInput = 0;
  do {
    if ($inputs[$currentInput]['row']->email === $minimumInput->email) {
      mergeDataToOutputRow($currentOutput, $inputs[$currentInput]['row']);
      $fetch = $inputs[$currentInput]['statement']->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
      if ($fetch === FALSE) {
        array_splice($inputs, $currentInput, 1); // that input is exhausted
      } else {
        $inputs[$currentInput]['row'] = $fetch;
      }
    } else {
      $currentInput++;
    }
  } while ($currentInput < count($inputs));
  // None of the inputs now match CURRENTOUTPUT
  output($currentOutput);
}
```

This algorithm requires that the sorting in MySQL (`ORDER BY email`) is identical to the sorting in PHP (`$row->email < $minimumInput->email`). How can I confirm that this requirement is met for all possible (*including non-latin*) inputs?

Comment: `<` on strings rarely makes sense. and if you're dealing with non-latin (I'm guessing you mean non-ascii) it's even worse. PHP isn't unicode aware, and will compare things MUCH differently than mysql, because php will be comparing characters-as-single-bytes, not characters-that-may-be-multibyte.

Comment: Here is the final code that lets you combine multiple mysql queries and combine records if they have same unique key: https://gist.github.com/fulldecent/a4cac03087cadec4c275a54317a6f623

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY email COLLATE utf8_bin` in MySQL so that you get the same ordering as in PHP, thereby letting your 'merge' work.  (At least, I think this is a solution.)